# Why do we need an objective lens in a scanning electron microscope?

Tags: electromagnetism, lenses, microscopy

[image]

I've been studying scanning electron microscopes quite a bit but can't seem to get my head around why we need objective lenses.

On paper I don't see a reason, if we would want to focus the electron beam in 1 small spot, why we cant put our specimen directly in the focal/crossover point beneath the condenser lens.

Why do we bother with the lens aperture and the objective lens behind it?

After reading in about 3 different sources I think I finally understood a basic concept of optics. That the condenser lens and objective lens are supposed to work together. I can't quite say why but it seem that neither lens could do the job alone. We always (? not sure here) need both to focus the beam nicely in 1 spot. Can anyone give me some insights into this? [Source](https://www.jeol.co.jp/en/applications/pdf/sm/sem_atoz_all.pdf)

Comment: Because subjective lenses would bring their own biases into the images.

Answer (score 0):

There are really two issues that enter through practical design needs:

- The aperture cleans up the beam a lot, making it possible to make a clean spot
- The combination provides larger “relief” to the spot, so that it’s further from the lenses. Since these are magnetic fields, not glass, it’s best to give them some room.

Comment: So the main advantage is the aperture and the 'distance'?
Could you maybe explain why it's good to 'give them some room'?

Answer (score 0):

The condenser and aperture shape the electron beam but since the signal is recorded by a point detector, the beam must be rastered across the sample. The objective scans (hence the S in SEM) the electron beam across the sample in two dimensions, and the elastically scattered electrons are measured at each point.

This is analogous to the galvanometer scanners in a laser scanning confocal microscope. The laser is rastered across the specimen and the emitted photons are collected by a detector (photomultiplier tube or avalanche photodiode) at each point.